# How to prove that $x^2 + 3y^2 = 1$ is contained inside of the unit ball?

Tags: geometry, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

What is the best way to show that $S = \{(x,y) | x^2 + 3y^2 = 1\}$ is contained in the unit ball without graphing the set?

Comment: what can you conclude about $x^2 + y^2$ on your set?

Comment: @WillJagy $(x^2 + y^2) = (x+iy)(x-iy)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$y^2$ is positive, so $y^2 \leq 3y^2$. Thus, if $x,y$ are such that $x^2 + 3y^2 = 1$ then $x^2+y^2 \leq 1$.

Comment: Quite nice but counter intuitive

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2 + 3y^2 = 1 \quad\implies\quad x^2+y^2=1-2y^2\leq 1$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $(x,y)\in S$ is outside the unit ball. Then $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}>1$, or just $x^2+y^2>1$. But we also have $x^2+3y^2=1$. Subtracting this from the above gives $-2y^2>0$, which is impossible since $y^2$ is nonnegative.

Comment: Correct, but it's a lot of extra work to frame everything by way of contradiction.